# Javascript Auto screen size testing

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, html

Hy aLL,
i have used a javascript code that when a link is chosen, an image will slowly pop-up and slowly blackify's the background.
When pressed on an ipad, not all the background will become black! When in the CSS, i have put that the background will take 100% of the screen,
Here's my code : 
The part of the CSS:

```
  #backgroundPopup{  
  display:none;  
  position:fixed;  
  _position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6*/  
  width:100%;  
  height:100%;  
  top:0;  
  left:0;  
  background:#000000;  
  border:1px solid #cecece;  
  z-index:5;  
  }
```

When i use my debugger, i see that automatically the screen size is detected at the first time my browser starts, but in the Ipad's case, sometimes i zoom out or a change orientation, then some annoying white will show!
So i need a way to keep javascript testing for screen size at any change. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes using percentages for the width and height may be tricky. In your case you could try to set the width and height to the number in pixels corresponding to the 100% of height and width (via Javascript/jQuery), to avoid using percentages.

Hope this helps!

**Edit**:

With [this script](http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/get-viewport-size-javascript/): You can get the size of the browser window (not the screen resolution, only the useful size). I think it is what you want. Having this information you can set via javascript the height and width of your background popup just fine.

Comment: I saw a link and decided to revisit this question, although I imagine you have already solved it. With this script: http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/get-viewport-size-javascript/. You can get the size of the browser window (not the screen resolution, only the useful size). I think it is what you want. Having this information you can set via javascript the height and width of your background popup just fine. Regards, Romén.

Answer (score 0):

When the viewport size changes the `window.onresize` event fires. Hook the event and resize the black element accordingly.